# Plotting multiple sets of information from file with Gnuplot

Tags: plot, charts, gnuplot

I have a file that looks like this:

```
0 0.000000
1 0.357625
2 0.424783
3 0.413295
4 0.417723
5 0.343336
6 0.354370
7 0.349152
8 0.619159
9 0.871003
0.415044
```

The last line is the mean of the N entries listed right above it. What I want to do is to plot a chart that has each point listed and a line with the mean value. I know it involves replot in some way but I can't read the last value separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two passes using the stats command to get the necessary data

```
stats datafile u 1 nooutput
stats datafile u ($0==(STATS_records-1)?$1:1/0) nooutput
```

The first pass of stats will summarize the data file.  What we are actually interested in is the number of records in the file, which will be saved in the variable *STATS_records*.

The second pass will compute a column to analyze.  If the line number (the value of **$0**) is equal to one less than the number of records (lines are numbered from 0, so this is the last line), than we get this value, otherwise we get an invalid value.  This causes the stats command to only look at this last line.  Now the value of the last line is stored in *STATS_max* (or *STATS_min* and several other variables).

Now we can create the plot using

```
plot datafile u 1:2, STATS_max
```

where we explicitly state columns 1 and 2 to make the first plot specification ignore that last line (actually, if we just do `plot datafile` it should default to this column selection and automatically ignore that last line, but this makes certain).  This produces

[image]

---

An alternative way is to use external programs to filter the data.  For example, if we have the linux command *tail* available, we could do<sup>1</sup>

```
ave = system("tail -1 datafile")
plot datafile u 1:2, ave+0
```

Here, *ave* will contain the last row of the file as a string.  In the plot command we add 0 to it to force it to change to a number (otherwise gnuplot will think it is a filename).

Other external programs can be used to read that last line as well.  For example, the following call to python3 (using Windows style shell quotes) does the same:

```
ave = system('python -c "print(open(datafile,\"r\").readlines()[-1])"')
```

or the following using AWK (again with Windows style shell quotes) has the same result:

```
ave = system('awk "END{print}"')
```

or even using Perl (again with Windows shell quotes):

```
ave = system('perl -lne "END{print $last} $last=$_" datafile')
```

---

**<sup>1</sup>** This use of *tail* uses a now obsolete (according to the GNU manuals) command line option.  Using `tail -n 1 datafile` is the recommended way.  However, this shorter way is less to type, and if forward compatibility is not needed (ie you are using this script once), there is no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Gnuplot ignores those lines with missing data (for example, the last line of your datafile has no column 2). Then, you can simply do the following:

```
stats datafile using 2 nooutput
plot datafile using 1:2, STATS_mean
```

The result:
[image: stats_mean]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using external tools or using `stats` (unless the value hasn't been calculated already, but in your example it has).
During plotting of the data points you can assign the value of the first column, e.g. to the variable `mean`.
Since the last row doesn't contain a second column, no datapoint will be plotted, but this last value will be hold in the variable `mean`.

If you replace `reset session` with `reset` and read the data from a file instead of a datablock, this will work with gnuplot 4.6.0 or even earlier versions.

**Minimal solution:**

```
plot FILE u (mean=$1):2, mean
```

**Script:** (nicer plot and including data for copy & paste & run)

```
### plot values as points and last value from column 1 as line
reset session

$Data <<EOD
0 0.000000
1 0.357625
2 0.424783
3 0.413295
4 0.417723
5 0.343336
6 0.354370
7 0.349152
8 0.619159
9 0.871003
0.415044
EOD

set key top center
plot $Data u (mean=$1):2 w p pt 7 lc rgb "blue" ti "Data", \
                    mean w l lw 2 lc rgb "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]